# Use multiselect false property with checkboxCellTemplate

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, ng-grid

I have an `ng-grid` that utilizes the `showSelectionCheckbox: true` property with a custom `checkboxCellTemplate`.

If I remove `checkboxCellTemplate` I get the functionality I want where only one `checkbox` can be clicked at a time and clicking another `checkbox` will remove the selection from the previous one.

I need the template to call a specific function so my question comes down to what property to I have to pass in the template so it can be aware of the `multiselect` property?

The plunker can be found at http://plnkr.co/edit/nULoI4?p=preview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to clarify you're wondering if you can get all the values that are selected when you call a function?  Don't you already have this setup in the `$scope.selections`.  You could pass this in the function of the template by doing something like this `ng-click="getDeliveryLocation({{selections}})"`.

Another thought is that you use `afterSelectionChange:function(){}` and add in whatever you need instead of the ng-click on the checkmarks.  This will remove some of the odd issues you have between the different selects.